# D3 collapsible Tree different node colors

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, tree

I've got a collapsible tree in d3.js. My goal is to color the nodes by the "type"-attribute. A node with type = "str" should be filled red for example, while the ones with type = "elem" should be colored green. I just can't get it to work. Can someone help me please.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Tree Collapsible Example</title>

<style>

    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node circle {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .node text {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
        width = 1000 - margin.right - margin.left,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
        duration = 750,
        root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// load the external data
d3.json("dendrogram02.json", function(error, treeData) {
    root = treeData[0];
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;
    update(root);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

function update(source) {

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
            links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 80; });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
            .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 1e-6)
            .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 20 : 13; })
            .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "-.8em" : ".35em"; })
            .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
            .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
            .attr("r", 4)
            .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
            .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
            .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
            .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
            .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
            .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
                return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
            });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
                return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
            })
            .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the corresponding .json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "1",
    "type": "sources",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "0",
        "type": "dfasdl",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "companies",
            "type": "seq",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "row",
                "type": "elem",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "companyName",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "industry",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "telephoneCompany",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "date_entered",
                    "type": "datetime"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "contacts",
            "type": "seq",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "row",
                "type": "elem",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "title",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "contactFirstName",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "contactLastName",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "telephoneUS",
                    "type": "str"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "employees",
            "type": "seq",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "row",
                "type": "elem",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "position",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "employeeFirstName",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "employeeLastName",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "telephoneUS",
                    "type": "str"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "vendors",
            "type": "seq",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "row",
                "type": "elem",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "type",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "vendorFirstName",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "vendorLastName",
                    "type": "str"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "telephone",
                    "type": "str"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is modify

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
```

according to your requirements:

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          if(d.type == "str") return "red";
          if(d.type == "elem") return "green";
        });
```

As you're setting the fill colour twice, you also have to do this for the update selection:

```
 nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 4)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          if(d.type == "str") return "red";
          if(d.type == "elem") return "green";
        });
```

Comment: You also need to do that for the update selection. I've clarified that.