# How to add custom conditional colors in D3 tree nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, r2d3

I am learning D3js and I would like to use condition to assign colors to nodes of a tree diagram. For example, if the type of data is "str", the node color will become "read" or "green" if it is "elem".

I refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524668/d3-collapsible-tree-different-node-colors) and add the condition, but it turns out all nodes become black instead of "red" or "green".

Does anyone know the reason on this behavior?

Here is D3 code:

```
// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
//var treeData = data
var treeData = data;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = svg.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}


function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          if(d.type == "str") return "red";
          if(d.type == "elem") return "green";
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
          if(d.type == "str") return "red";
          if(d.type == "elem") return "green";
     })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}
```

data:

```
{
  "type": "str",
  "name": "Canada",
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "elem",
      "name": "Newfoundland",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "str",
          "name": "St. John's"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "elem",
      "name": "PEI",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "str",
          "name": "Charlottetown"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "elem",
      "name": "Nova Scotia",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "str",
          "name": "Halifax"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: it seems like the `d.type` is undefined, but I do not know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3-hiearchy produces a new data array, to avoid collisions between properties of the hierarchy and properties of the data, it places the data associated with a given node into a `data` property.

D3-hierarchy does this to preserve the original data, for example, your data has a `children` property, d3-hierarchy produces a set of nodes that also have a `children` property, so to keep both and avoid collisions, the original data is moved to the `data` property.

So instead of `d.type` you need to use `d.data.type`.

For reference, each node returned by d3-hierarchy has only the following properties:

```
node.data - the associated data, as specified to the constructor.
node.depth - zero for the root node, and increasing by one for each descendant generation.
node.height - zero for leaf nodes, and the greatest distance from any descendant leaf for internal nodes.
node.parent - the parent node, or null for the root node.
node.children - an array of child nodes, if any; undefined for leaf nodes.
node.value - the summed value of the node and its descendants; optional, see node.sum and node.count.
```

(from [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy))